# Android программирование считается практикой Java?

Tags: java, android

Учу Java пока только теорию читал книжки, смотрел видосы и т.д есть базовые знания и здесь мне многие советуют не зубрить теорию а начать практиковаться, так вот мне нравится Android и я думаю считается ли это практикой Java, все таки там своя андроидовская Java, или поискать проекты на чистой Jave ?? Вот как вы думаете. И вообще как мне научиться самой технике написания, т.к я сажусь за комп и не знаю с чего начать, куда нажать )) и тому подобное.

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря после нескольких месяцев разработки под Android я лично для себя увидел что это не есть полноценная практика Java. Да не спорю что синтаксис одинаковый, что используется много от Java, ООП например, или условные операторы. НО! Все эти действия направлены на работу с пользовательским интерфейсом. Вся работа заключается в использовании уже готовых функций, например реализация нажатий на кнопку.

Лично я могу вам посоветовать определится что именно вам интересно. Я например начал заниматься мобильной разработкой еще зимой потому-что нужно было писать диплом)) в итоге пришлось еще и инженерию изучать, чтобы связать микроконтроллер с телефонной программой. В процессе работы я понял что это действительно интересно и мне захотелось идти дальше.

После нескольких месяцев разработки я понял, что да, Java используется, но не слишком. У меня одногрупник занимался программированием на Java и я понял что в android этот язык использует очень мало своих возможностей. Да сейчас меня начнут закидывать помидорами, что типа это я мало использую Java в android и вообще она юзается там очень много, не спорю может мое мнение не правильное, но оно мое))

Java это очень крутой язык программирования, и его можно учить очень долго но все-равно его не будешь знать полностью. Лично мне кажется что изучение Java это намного серьезнее чем программирование на android, ведь если бы не было java то не было и android.

Поэтому я вам советую изначально определится с тем что вам хочется делать. Именно хочется, к чему лежит душа, а не то что нужно делать. Если вы будете заниматься приятным делом то оно вам принесет не только удовольствие, но и денежку. Я надеюсь что я не встречусь со шквалом критики вызванной выражением своего мнения. Удачи в дальнейших разработках, я верю что у вас все получится :)

Comment: полноценное использование java в андроид - это бизнес-логика приложения, ui-интерфейсы различны и специфичны, но алгоритмы решения бизнес-задач одинаковы в основном (то, что приложение должно **делать**, потому что приложения, которые просто показывают кнопки мало полезны для пользователя)

Comment: Вы зачем отделяете Java от Android'а? Все абсолютно так же программируется, только добавляется UI и специфичные андроиду вещи.

Comment: @Flippy, вероятнее всего вы правы, просто походу я еще не всю джаву использую у себя в разработке)

Answer (score 1):

Если только Java core и то весьма сомнительно. Андроид имеет свой весьма специфический фреймворк и архитектуру, которые в десктопной или web/серверной java никаким образом и никогда не пригодится. С другой стороны будет потрачено очень много времени на именно специфику  этого фреймворка.

Если ваша цель десктопные, web или серверные Java-приложения, то практика на андроид-разработке будет самым худшим выбором и даст вам очень мало, собственно, практики в этих направлениях.

Соответственно, если ваша цель мобильная разработка, то практика по десктопным и серверным приложениям так же будет мало полезна, поэтому сначала нужно определится с направлением. Java используется в сотнях разных платформ и фреймворков и большинство из них узкоспециализированы и будут мало полезны в других областях применения этого языка.

Универсальными знаниями, полезными во всех применениях будет консольная Java core, с нее и стоит начать обучение, освоится с синтаксисом, операторами языка, конструкциями, концепцией ООП, работой с объектами и вот это вот все, потом уже определяся с платформой, фреймворком и более узким направлением

Начать нужно с установки среды разработки, как унивесальная под множество платформ и фреймворков - IntelliJ IDEA. потом есть множество "hello word"-ов, смотришь, читаешь, повторяешь, постепенно втягиваешься- усложняешь, решаешь свои задачи или бросаешь ..

Answer (score 0):

Это будет отличной практикой **но только если** вы будете понимать все, что пишите. Гарантирую, что у вас все в голове уляжется если вы будете активно использовать Android SDK, а ещё лучше заглядывать внутрь исходных кодов

Comment: если цель не android-разработка, то такая "практика" будет только сбивать с толку, потому что точка вхождения в android-программирование весьма высока, не говоря уже о том, что так же и весьма далека от "классической" java-разработки. Одно только отсутствие метода-входа `main()` и жизненный цикл - вещи нетривиальные, но требующие понимания с самого старта и нигде на java-платформах больше не используемые. Чтобы понимать "все что пишите" лучшая практика - консольная java-core, без заморочек фреймворков и  платформ, особенно для человека, который не знает " куда нажать ..". такое мое мнение

Comment: @pavlofff, не знаю, я вот когда начинал элементарно не понимал код установки слушателя например. Потом понял, что это - метод, это - анонимный класс и т.д...

Comment: ну вообще слушатель - это универсальный паттерн "интерфейс обратного вызова" (он же callback), который используется в Java повсеместно, а не только в андроид. погружаться в такой специфичный фреймворк для того, чтобы понять колбэки нет прямой необходимости

Comment: @pavlofff, я же просто привёл пример)